# Как сделать вложенные друг в друга LinkedHashMap оптимальным способом?

Tags: java, hashmap, linked-list

Суть: получаю ответ JSON и кастую его к LinkedHashMap (далее ЛХМ). Получается, чтобы достать нужный параметр, я в каждом ЛХМ по ключу беру следующий ЛХМ и так до конца, пока не доберусь до нужного значения. Далее, мне нужно СОЗДАТЬ такой многослойный ЛХМ для тестирования, т.е. симулировать ответ полученный от сервиса. Если делать это в лоб, получается много кода:

```
        LinkedHashMap lhmResponse = new LinkedHashMap();
        LinkedHashMap data = new LinkedHashMap();
        LinkedHashMap images = new LinkedHashMap();
        LinkedHashMap original = new LinkedHashMap();
        original.put("url", "test");
        images.put("original", original);
        data.put("images", images);
        lhmResponse.put("data", data);
```

так работает, всё ОК, но много букаф.
второй способ:

```
lhmResponse.put("data", new LinkedHashMap()
                .put("images", new LinkedHashMap()
                        .put("original", new LinkedHashMap()
                                .put("url", "test"))));
```

компилируется, но при распечатке toString - data=null. Вопрос: можно ли починить второй способ, или как написать оптимально такую сборку. Первый способ слишком громоздкий и возникает проблема, что мне надо два вложенных ЛХМ, но отличающихся последним значением, и тогда при изменении значение меняется в обоих ЛХМ. Приходится по первому способу создавать в 2 раза больше ЛХМ-ов.

ПС(ЗЫ): ДТО не предлагать, не хочу возиться с ломбоком, он только мне геморроя добавил. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может {{}} ?

```
Map lhmResponse = new LinkedHashMap() {{
    put("data", new LinkedHashMap() {{
        put("images", new LinkedHashMap() {{
            put("original", new LinkedHashMap() {{
                put("url", "test");
            }});
        }});
    }});
}};
```

toString():

```
{data={images={original={url=test}}}}
```

PS Только Raw Type это, конечно, неправильно. Убрал типизацию для лаконичности примера.

Comment: Всё так, работает - большое спасибо, только я так и не понял, какую роль выполняют {{ двойные скобки.

Comment: Внешние скобки - объявление анонимного класса. Внутренние скобки - нестатический блок инициализации в этом классе.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!