# Как получить данные из вложенного LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, java-hashmap, hashmap

А как достать значение "test" отсюда?

```
Map<String, Object> response = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {{
    put("data", new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("images", new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("original", new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {{
                put("url", "test");
            }});
        }});
    }});
}};
```

response.get("url") = null

response.get("data.images.original.url") = null

response.get("data").get("images").get("original").get("url")

```
Compilation failed:
cannot find symbol
symbol:   method get(java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.Object
```

> [Как сделать вложенные друг в друга LinkedHashMap оптимальным способом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1232494/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0-linkedhashmap-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object url = ((Map<String,Object>) ((Map<String,Object>) ((Map<String,Object>) response.get("data")).get("images")).get("original")).get("url");
```

Полный и развернутый [ответ на англ.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69402260/how-to-get-data-from-nested-linkedhashmap/69402322#69402322).

Answer (score 0):

чтобы использовать упомянутый в вопросе "синтаксис ключа" `response.get("data.images.original.url")` можно развернуть вложенные map:

```java
        Map<String, Object> tmp = response.entrySet().stream()
                .flatMap(entry -> ((Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue()).entrySet().stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                o -> entry.getKey() + '.' + o.getKey(),
                                Map.Entry::getValue)
                        ).entrySet().stream()
                )
                .flatMap(entry -> ((Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue()).entrySet().stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                o -> entry.getKey() + '.' + o.getKey(),
                                Map.Entry::getValue)
                        ).entrySet().stream()
                )
                .flatMap(entry -> ((Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue()).entrySet().stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                o -> entry.getKey() + '.' + o.getKey(),
                                Map.Entry::getValue)
                        ).entrySet().stream()
                )
                .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));


        String key = "data.images.original.url";
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0}={1}", key, tmp.get(key)));
```

Вывод консоли:
`data.images.original.url=test`